# Error status returned by successful thread creation in C

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

I am trying to write an application in `C` which uses threads by using `thread.h` defined in `C11` specification.

I checked [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_errors) and [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dinkum%2Ftopic%2Fcpp11%2Fthreads.html) and both resources say that error status are **unspecified** or **.....**.

Please point me to a source which has this information.

Comment: The return value of `thrd_create` is one of the enum values. The _specific_ value is unspecified, `thrd_success` can be equal to 0, 1 or anything else. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the point of having enumeration values for that purpose. You should never compare the return value to any literal number but to these constants.

```
int err = thrd_create(...);
if (err == thrd_error) {
  // handle error here
}
```

Comment: i forgot that enum automatically assigns values from 0 unless specifically allocated a value. yes, i agree with you. thanks for the answer